# How to fix Navigation Bar Item animating to side after pushing a VC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have an iOS app where I am creating a custom view for navigation item.
The navigation item works great and places itself right every time when I come to the screen.

[image]
However, when a VC is pushed from this screen and I come back to the screen, the navigation item appears at the right place momentarily but is immediately shifted to the right side corner.

[image]

I do suspect this is related to the animation of the navigation bar during the transition but even after trying multiple work around it still happens.
Below is the code for the navigation item view.

```
 UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    v.opaque = NO;

    UILabel *subtitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(v.bounds.origin.x, v.bounds.origin.y + v.bounds.size.height * 0.6, v.bounds.size.width, v.bounds.size.height * 0.3))];
    subtitleLabel.text = subtitle;
    subtitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];//Font adjusted to accomodate text into size
    subtitleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    subtitleLabel.opaque = NO;
    subtitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    subtitleLabel.textColor = defaultSubtitleTextColor;
    subtitleLabel.shadowOffset = defaultShadowOffset;
    subtitleLabel.shadowColor = defaultShadowColor;

    [v addSubview:subtitleLabel];


    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(v.bounds.origin.x, v.bounds.origin.y + v.bounds.size.height * 0.1, v.bounds.size.width, v.bounds.size.height * 0.5))];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    titleLabel.opaque = NO;
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.textColor = defaultTextColor;
    titleLabel.shadowOffset = defaultShadowOffset;
    titleLabel.shadowColor = defaultShadowColor;

    [v addSubview:titleLabel];

    navItem.titleView = v;
```

Spent a lot of time already on this, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try placing autolayout constraints on the title view and it’s child UilabelViews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else in similar situation, It was to do with `intrinsicContentSize`. After setting it to return `UILayoutFittingExpandedSize`. The issue was gone.